# Plone CMS - multiple domains? user permissions?

Tags: python, plone

Good Afternoon, 
We are currently investigating using Plone for our CMS solution.

Ideally we would move our current websites accross to Plone, and then move across other applications later in the project.

I have a couple of Questions that Should be easy, but I have not found direct answers here;

- Does Plone have the ability to run multiply domains, So say 5 domains
  could run off one instance of Plone, and dependant on the domain,
  different content and pages would display? Would this be a simple exercise?
- The ability to have multiply user hierarchy, some with Editing ability, but can not post changes, and other who can approve the content before it is published and edit when needed?

We are not scared of the programming or developing additional applications, and we are also looking at employing a company who knows Plone as well to guide our process.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow.  If you have multiple questions, even if they have similar topics (which is natural, since they arise from working on the same project), you should still ask more than one question.  Also be sure to ask questions that have an objectively correct answer, preferably in the form of code, question's that revolve around the suitability of a particular framework to a particular application cannot be answered in that way, since most any framework can be made to work for an application, especially since the only person that knows about the needs of your project is you.

Comment: I've flagged for transfer to webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can have multiple Plone sites for each domain on the same Plone instance(s)/zeo setup.  I would recommend you use [collective.recipe.filestorage](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.recipe.filestorage) and give each site it's own data.fs ([instructions on how to use this here](http://webteam.medsci.ox.ac.uk/integrators-developers/separatedatafs)) in case you want to split them up later.  If you just want to have each domain point to a separate section of the same website you can do that as well.

Yes you can customize the workflow and user groups however you would like.  There is some basic [information here.](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/plone-4-user-manual/collaboration-and-workflow/referencemanual-all-pages)

Answer (score 0):

1. What exactly is your use case for serving one instance of Zope over several domain names, with different content? In any case, this could probably be achieved with a combination of Apache `VirtualHost`s (serve the site via multiple domain names) and `mod_rewrite` (to serve different content for each domain.) Really, though, you may be better off running separate instances of Plone.
2. Zope does support permissions. I haven't read the [documentation on permissions](https://plone.org/documentation/kb/understanding-permissions) closely to determine if the Zope permissions model meets your exact needs, but you should [start here](https://plone.org/documentation/kb/understanding-permissions).